# Python data structure. The values are not getting print

Tags: python

```
# Linked List

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=None
        self.next=None
    def setData(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def getData(self):
        return self.data
    def setNext(self,next):
        self.next=next
    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

class LinkedList:
    def BuildList(self):
        print("Enter the array :-")
        x=int(input("Enter the number :-"))
        newNode=Node()
        start=Node()
        head=Node()
        head=start
        start=0
        while(x!=-1):
            newNode.setData(x)
            if(start==0):

                newNode.setNext(None)
                start=newNode
            else:
                ptr=start
                while(ptr.getNext()!=None):
                    ptr=ptr.getNext()
                ptr.setNext(newNode)
                newNode.setNext(None)
            x=int(input())
        print("Thus the list is ")
        ptr=start
        while(ptr!=None):
            print("The data is %d",ptr.getData())
            ptr=ptr.getNext()

charan=LinkedList()
charan.BuildList()
```

Comment: What input are you giving the program, and what output are you getting, and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: You really don't need `{get,set}{Data,Next}` in `Node`. Just use the attributes directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You are adding `newNode` to the linked list several times, but you only create it once. This creates multiple references to one object; you probably wanted a single reference to each of several independent objects.
2. You got the syntax wrong for percent-style string interpolation in the `print` statement.

Move `newNode=Node()` to the inside of the while loop, and change your print statement to `print("The data is %d" % ptr.getData())`.

```
# Linked List

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=None
        self.next=None
    def setData(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def getData(self):
        return self.data
    def setNext(self,next):
        self.next=next
    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

class LinkedList:
    def BuildList(self):
        print("Enter the array :-")
        x=int(input("Enter the number :-"))
        start=Node()
        head=Node()
        head=start
        start=0
        while(x!=-1):
            newNode=Node()
            newNode.setData(x)
            if(start==0):

                newNode.setNext(None)
                start=newNode
            else:
                ptr=start
                while(ptr.getNext()!=None):
                    ptr=ptr.getNext()
                ptr.setNext(newNode)
                newNode.setNext(None)
            x=int(input())
        print("Thus the list is ")
        ptr=start
        while(ptr!=None):
            print("The data is %d" % ptr.getData())
            ptr=ptr.getNext()

charan=LinkedList()
charan.BuildList()
```

Result:

```
Enter the array :-
Enter the number :-1
2
3
-1
Thus the list is
The data is 1
The data is 2
The data is 3
```